# Need to use ReadConsoleOutputCharacter, but it isn't prototyped in Smallwin.inc?

Tags: winapi, console-application, masm, irvine32

I'm writing a 32-bit assembly program with MASM and the Irvine32 library, and am trying to save the contents currently written in the console window to a buffer. As far as my research on the topic has told me, (and please correct me if I'm wrong), I need the ReadConsoleOutputCharacter Win32 API function for this. However, when invoking it, I get told that the symbol is undefined. In the same program, invoking another function like WriteConsole works.

To investigate, I checked the Smallwin.inc file that comes with the Irvine library, and for some reason, the function isn't prototyped in there. It's strange because the function is listed in Table 11-2 of the book, the book explicitly says that all Win32 functions are supported by the Irvine library, and Smallwin.inc even prototyped the Write counterpart of this very function! I can't seem to find an answer as to why the function isn't included. Could someone help me figure out how I can use this function, maybe by adding the appropriate prototype to Smallwin.inc or including something else within the Irvine library?

I'm coding on Visual Studio Community 2019, using the Irvine32 library. If there's anything else I should add to my question please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The API call is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutputcharacter). Should be reasonably easy to derive a [function prototype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/proto) from that.

Comment: Take a cue from "small".  It has the same parameters as WriteConsoleOutputCharacter, so just copy/paste its definition and change the function name.

Comment: Managed to figure it out by writing the PROTO myself. Thanks for the help!